# Jquery access id of appended div

Tags: jquery, html, append

I cannot access the IDs of jQuery appended elements.

I have tried enclosing the appended HTML in $() but it is still not working.

There is a somewhat similar question here but I haven't been able to adapt it - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107267/getting-access-to-a-jquery-element-that-was-just-appended-to-the-dom).

```
// fn to append html code to div
var addCode = function(html, div) {
    var $html = $(html);
    $("#"+div).append($html);

}

// generate a series of links
var str="";
for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    var random_integer = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);

    str+="<a href=\"#\" class=\"add_image\" id=\""+random_integer+"\">Receipt</a> ";
}

// on click test1 add string to div test2
$("#test1").on("click", function(){
    addCode(str, "test2");
});

// alert the link id
$(".add_image").on("click", function(){

    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    alert("link id="+id);

});
```

Here is the example http://jsfiddle.net/chakotha/7mw0m9ch/1/

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the last function to use event delegation for the dynamically added elements:

```
$(document).on("click", ".add_image",function(){
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    alert("link id="+id);
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7mw0m9ch/2/)**