# Get an element that was appended to the DOM dynamically using PURE JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, pure-js

Basically what the question says. I import HTML code from an external file and append it to my main html code:

```js
/**
 * Get the HTML contents from the URL specified in the filename and add them
 * to the before the bottom of the specified DOM element.
 * @param {string} filename The URL of the HTML file we want to import.
 * @param {DOM element} element The element to which we'll append the HTML code.
 */
function importHtml(filename, element) {
    let data = fetch(filename)
    .then(function(response) {
        // When the page is loaded convert it to text
        return response.text()
    })
    .then(function(html) {
        // Return the HTML contents of the file.
        element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {  
        console.log('Failed to fetch page: ', err);  
    });
    return data;
}
importHtml("html/includes/header.html", header);
```

I've tried to get access to that HTML code using:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
   const menu = document.querySelector('#menubar');
}
```

but it doesn't work. **It has to be PURE JS**.

I've looked but I can't seem to find the answer :/

Comment: There is not enough info here to help you here. Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: It is the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107267/getting-access-to-a-jquery-element-that-was-just-appended-to-the-dom) but with **PURE JS** instead.

Comment: Also my html element is imported from an HMTL file

Comment: "_I import HTML code from an external file and append it to my main html code._" can you show the code for it in your post?

Comment: @palaѕн how about now?