# Appended html element via jquery is not handled by jquery events

Tags: html, jquery

There are jquery script and html rendered using django template engine. I want the script would handle badges click events. Badge: `<span class="badge bg-primary" id="{{ tag.id }}">{{ tag }}</span>`. By pressing badge which is in `<div class="project-badges">` it should move to `<div class="all-badges">` and vise versa. And The script bellow does it, but when I want I moved an element from div to div and want to move it back it doesn't work. Moving an element in my case is removing it from one div and adding to another.

```
        $('span.badge.bg-primary').click(function(){
            $(this).remove()
            $(this).css({
                "transform": "scale(1.0)",
                "textDecoration": "none",
            })
            $(this).appendTo('div.all-badges')
            $('div.all-badges').append(' ')
        });

        $('span.badge.bg-danger').click(function(){
            $(this).remove()
            $(this).css("transform", "scale(1.0)")
            $(this).appendTo('div.project-badges')
            $('div.project-badges').append(' ')
        });
```

```
<div class="project-badges">   
    {% for tag in project.tag.all %}
<span class="badge bg-primary" id="{{ tag.id }}">{{ tag }}</span>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

<div class="all-badges">     
     {% for tag in tags %}
<span class="badge bg-danger" id="{{ tag.id }}">{{ tag }}</span>
     {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Your first step should be [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/remove/): *"Similar to `.empty()`, the `.remove()` method takes elements out of the DOM. Use `.remove()` when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. **In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed. To remove the elements without removing data and events, use `.detach()` instead.**"* *(my emphasis)*

Comment: Maybe try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107267/getting-access-to-a-jquery-element-that-was-just-appended-to-the-dom
Please create a fiddle with your code so we can easily try and see the problem

Comment: @Reynadan - The problem is that `remove` removes event handlers, see the linked dupetarget's answers.

Comment: That's a better way to do it indeed !